# Ordered NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa, nsdictionary, hashtable

How can I preserve the way that I add objects to `NSDictionary`?

I realize that there is no specific order to values in `NSDictionary`, but in my case I need the preserve the order that I add using `setValue:forKey:`, like an array.

How could I do this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is hash mapped for faster retrieval. You are not allowed to fix its order.

If you want to store in order you should use arrays.

Or you have to use some complex way, keep on appending an `int orderNumber`(You need to increment it after every setObject/setValue) with the key. to storing and retrieval as :

```
NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary new];
NSString *key=....;
[dict setValue:@"some  value" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%@",orderNumber, key]];
```

---

Alternatively you can use an array having one dictionary per index.

---

Another way would be to use a custom class as

```
@interface ....
    @property(...) NSInteger index;
    @property(...) NSString *key;
    @property(...) id object;
    // and methods to retrieve based on key, based on index etc
@end
```

EDIT 2:

Found very similar to what I posted an year ago, see this [OrderedDictionary](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html).

Comment: I realize I could use arrays, but I need to store both Keys and Values, something which NSArray doesn't allow.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
static int index;
[myDictionary setValue:someValue forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d", index++]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to:

- Track the order separately by maintaining an array of the keys, in the order you added them.
- Add the order as an attribute of the object you are storing in the dictionary.

I would prefer the second approach as it keeps all the information in one place.  If the object you are storing is not defined by you, then you might need to create a subclass of that object, or encapsulate it in one of your own objects, with the additional *order* member.